# Product Detail Page is blank

Tags: blocks

have issue on product detail page clicking any product it redirect to product detail page.
but show only image with mouse over zoom effect and left side bar and footer missing.

[image]

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was your page working before?  Did you install a new template?

This is a common issue when there is conflicting or incomplete PHP in your template - have you made any changes to your template or installed any new modules?  The fastest way to resolve these issues is to "undo" any recent changes you've made (even if they seem innocuous, like updating the HTML).

If you've just installed a new layout, there are a few possibilities: first, the layout installed incorrectly.  Try reuploading it.  Second, it might not be compatible with your version of Magento, which is giving you the error.  Third, it might be compatible with your version of Magento, but not a third-party module you've installed.

If you haven't made any recent changes and your template was working before now, start the debugging process linked by Marius above. The good news is that if this is a sudden change you should be able to link it back to something you've done in the last few hours or days.

Comment: same thing uploaded on other server and its working properly and locally also. i checked everything but still same issue., file permission and url issue is not thr.

Comment: and its not working proper from starting

Answer (score 0):

May be permission problem so kindly check the phtml file permissions.
maybe css or other url issue.